# One Form Multiple Models

Tags: django

I am struggling to find good information on how to display data, or reference data from multiple models on one form.  Right now I generate a listview with my servicereports model.  In that list view I pick out a few columns to display (Customer, Date, Originator).  The customer column is actually filled with primary key references to another model, the customers model.  How can I take that pk and use it to reference the actual customer name from another model?

models.py

```
class Companies(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(db_column='Company Name', max_length=50)
    billing_address = models.CharField(db_column='Billing Address', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    company_id = models.AutoField(db_column='Company ID', primary_key=True)
class ServiceRecords(models.Model):
    sr_id = models.CharField(db_column='SR ID', primary_key=True, max_length=50)  
    company_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Company ID', blank=True, null=True)
...
```

views.py

```
class ServiceReportIndex(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    context_object_name = 'all_servicereports'
    login_url = 'login'
    template_name = 'servicereport/servicereport_index.html'
    queryset = ServiceRecords.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ServiceReportIndex, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['companies'] = TblCompanies.objects.all()
        return context
```

So in this case I want to use the customers.company_name within the list I am generating using the ServiceRecords model.

template.html

```
<p><a href="{% url 'servicereport:servicereport_detail' servicereport.sr_id %}">{{ customers.company_name }}</a></p>
```

Comment: Are you asking about a form or just a generic view? I don't see a form here...

Comment: For now, I guess a generic view is more pertinent.  Eventually I will need to learn how to do forms with multiple models as well.